# JavaScript object value undefined

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, promise

it passes the object to the function but I don't know why, despite the fact that it is visible there, I cannot return individual elements of this object because it shows "undefined" in the console logs. Anyone have any idea what I should do or am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
    async function getMonitors(){
        try {
            let res = await fetch(API_URL+"/"+API_VERSION+"/status/monitors/"+location.hostname+"/list");
            var data = await res.json();
            if(data.success){
                delete data.success;
                return data;
            }else{
                e=data.message;
            }
        } catch(error){
            e=error;
        }
        if(typeof e!="undefined"&&e!==null){system.error(e);}
    }
    function getMonitorsData(data){
        let totalMonitors = data.totalMonitors;
        console.log(data);
    }
    var m = getMonitors();
    var data = getMonitorsData(m);
```

Screen of the returned object in the function [Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuSZi.png)

Comment: `var m = await getMonitors();`

Comment: @GrafiCode that's not it "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

Comment: that's right, it must be wrapped in an async function, you can do `async function init() { var m = await getMonitors(); var data = getMonitorsData(m); }  init();`

Comment: Console log normally returns Promise to me, but when it gives me the key I want to return after date, it shows undefined

Comment: And do you know why if I want to download more data from the API, I have the same await async? I looked at what you sent and tried to do the same but without the expected results `function getMonitorsData(data){  let totalMonitors = data.totalMonitors; var monitors = []; data.monitors.forEach(function(m, i){ monitors[i] = getMonitor(m.monitor_id); }); $('#totalCount').text(totalMonitors); monitors.forEach(function(m, i){ console.log(m);}); if(typeof e!="undefined"&&e!==null){system.error(e);} console.log(monitors);}`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `await` keyword while calling `getMonitors()` function.

```
    async function getMonitors(){
    try {
        let res = await fetch(API_URL+"/"+API_VERSION+"/status/monitors/"+location.hostname+"/list");
        var data = await res.json();
        if(data.success){
            delete data.success;
            return data;
        }else{
            e=data.message;
        }
    } catch(error){
        e=error;
    }
    if(typeof e!="undefined"&&e!==null){system.error(e);}
}
function getMonitorsData(data){
    let totalMonitors = data.totalMonitors;
    console.log(data);
}
async function init() { 
    var m = await getMonitors(); 
    var data = getMonitorsData(m); 
}  
init();
```

Comment: It did not work, I tried it before but it showed me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules"

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to call the function and pass the data that are response from your API

```js
async function getMonitors(){
    try {
        let res = await fetch("https://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0");
        var data = await res.json();
        getMonitorsData(data) // here is what i added for passing response to function
        if(data.success){
            delete data.success;
            return data;
        }else{
            e=data.message;
        }
    } catch(error){
        e=error;
    }
    if(typeof e!="undefined"&&e!==null){system.error(e);}
}
function getMonitorsData(data){
    let totalMonitors = data.totalMonitors;
    console.log(data);
}
var m = getMonitors();
var data = getMonitorsData(m);
```